# Qt Quick c++: chess game, how can I update my 2darray model from QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to create a chess game in cpp and Qt6. I am new to both.
I was able to create a binding between my Board class (which contains a qvector of qvectors of squares) and QML. I am struggling however to update QML after creating a change in my model (2-way binding). I have tried implementing it with Q_PROPERTY notify and by subclassing QAbstractListModel, but I can't seem to get it working. :) I do not find examples online..

**chessviewmodel**

```
#ifndef CHESSVIEWMODEL_H
#define CHESSVIEWMODEL_H
#include <vector>
#include "board.h"
#include "board/Square.h"
#include "board/BoardFactory.h"
#include <string.h>

class ChessViewModel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString board NOTIFY boardChanged)
private:
    Board * board;

public:
    explicit ChessViewModel(QObject * parent = nullptr);
    void setBoard (Board & board);
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getPieceAt(const int row, const int column)  const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getPieceColourAt(const int row, const int column) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QString getSquareColourAt(const int row, const int column) const;
    Q_INVOKABLE void movePiece();
    virtual ~ChessViewModel() {
        delete board;
    }

signals:
    void boardChanged();
};

#endif // CHESSVIEWMODEL_H
```

**QML**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12


Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 8*73 + 200
    height: 8*73-3

    Rectangle {
        width: 8*73;
        height: 8*73-3;
        color: "black"

        Grid {
            id: grid;
            rows: 8;
            columns: 8;
            spacing: 3;

            Repeater {
                model: 64

                Rectangle {
                    id: square;
                    property int row: Math.floor(index/8);
                    property int col: index % 8;
                    property string squareColour: {
                        var color = "";
                        if(gameBoard != null) color = gameBoard.getSquareColourAt(row, col);
                        return color;
                    }
                    property string pieceColour: {
                        var color = "";
                        if(gameBoard != null) color = gameBoard.getPieceColourAt(row, col);
                        return color;
                    }
                    width: 70;
                    height: 70
                    color: squareColour
                    Text {
                        id: txt
                        text:  {
                            var p = "";
                            if(gameBoard != null) p = gameBoard.getPieceAt(row, col);
                            return p;
                        }
                        color: parent.pieceColour
                        font.pointSize: 30
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                   }

                   MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        hoverEnabled: true
                        onEntered: parent.color = "#3ec73a"
                        onExited: parent.color = parent.squareColour
                        onPressed: parent.opacity = 0.8
                        onReleased: parent.opacity = 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            x: 8 * 73;
            width: 200;
            height: 8*73-3;
            color: "#111212"

            Rectangle {
                width: 100;
                height: 50;
                color: "green"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                Text {
                    text: "Move piece"
                    color: "white";
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    onEntered: {
                        gameBoard.movePiece();
                        var p = "";
                        if(gameBoard != null) p = gameBoard.getPieceAt(square.row, square.col);
                        txt.text = p;
                    }
                    onClicked: gameBoard.movePiece();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Square class**

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
#include "pieces/Piece.h"
#include <QMetaEnum>

class Square
{
    public:
        Square();
        enum SquareColour { BLACK, WHITE };
        Square(SquareColour colour, Piece * piece);
        Piece & getPiece();
        QString getColour();
        void setPiece(Piece & piece);
        virtual ~Square();
    protected:

    private:
        SquareColour colour;
        Piece * piece;
};

#endif // SQUARE_H
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say you're subclassing `QAbstractListModel`, but I don't see that in your `ChessViewModel` or anywhere else.

Comment: "I can't seem to get it working" <- not a problem description. What _does_ the code do? Why is that wrong?

Comment: You might want to simplify while you work this out. Instead of a full board, try one square. Add (or remove) a piece from that square. If you can work that out, you'll have an example to use for your full project.

Comment: @JarMan No, I changed my code to try another solution.

Comment: @underscore_d, agreed, my question is not what is wrong in my code, but how would I go about creating this in Qt?

Comment: @JaMit, yea good idea I will try this tomorrow.